# How to make .pem files corresponding to keys human readale?

Tags: openssl

I have some .pem files containing public and private keys for rsa and dh, generated with genpkey (NOT certificates).

How do I make them human readable, as if they were generated with the -text option in genpkey ?

Comment: The `-text` option of genpkey is not about generation but about displaying. The `openssl rsa` and `openssl dhparam` commands have also `-text` option which show the  key given with the `-in` parameter as "human readable" text.

Comment: Actually my pem file contained a DH key (not rsa key or dh params) but you gave me the idea to try openssl pkey -text -in mypem and it worked :)